# How Cao Cao belongs to a family of eunuchs, if eunuchs don't have penis?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-china

I am watching Three kingdoms 2010 and in the first episode of that series, it was shown that Cao Cao stating himself belonging to a family of eunuchs but, I have read that Eunuchs don't have penis. So, was curious to know about it.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cao_Cao), _His father Cao Song was a _foster son_  of Cao Teng who in turn was one of the favourite eunuchs of Emperor Huan._ (My emphasis).

Comment: See: [Castration - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castration): ***Castration** is any action, surgical, chemical, or otherwise, by which **a male loses use of the testicles**: the male gonad. ... Castrated men—eunuchs – were often admitted to special social classes and were used particularly to staff bureaucracies and palace households: in particular, the harem.*

Comment: Seems obvious, you can have children and then get castrated.